# Change Recurrence to while

Tags: c#, arraylist, recurrence

I need to convert the recurrence code to the form while. More precisely, I have to write code that will complete the List with the next elements.
Here is the code I wrote. I will be grateful for your help.

```cs
namespace collatz
{
    class Collatz
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = 27;
            var list = new List<int>();
            var arr = new int[1];
            //arr.
            //CollatzRecursive(x, list);

            while (x > 1)
            {
                x = x % 2 == 0 ? x / 2 : 3 * x + 1;
                // asssignment = condtion ? whatifTrue : whatIfFalse;

                if (x % 2 == 0)
                {
                    x /= 2; // to samo co x = x / 2;
                    list.Add(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    x = 3 * x + 1;
                    list.Add(x);
                }
                //iterations++;
            }
            //console.log(str.length)
            Console.WriteLine(list);
        }

        //static void CollatzRecursive(int param, List<int> entries)
        //{
        //    if (param > 1)
        //    {
        //        entries.Add(param);
        //        CollatzRecursive(param % 2 == 0 ? param / 2 : 3 * param + 1, entries);
        //        return;
        //    }
        //    entries.Add(1);
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please what r u trying to do with the list

Comment: want to list how many actions were taken

Comment: @AmjadSaab It looks like they are doing the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) that if you start with any number and divide it by 2 if it's even or multiply it by 3 and add 1 if it's odd and then repeat that on the result you'll eventually get to 1, but capturing the sequence in a list.

Comment: @juharr excatly

Comment: It should just work if you do `while(x > 1) list.Add(x = x % 2 == 0 ? x / 2 : 3 * x + 1);`  Currently you're doing the division or multiplication and addition operations twice in each loop.  Or get rid of the `x = x % 2 == 0 ? x / 2 : 3 * x + 1;` and just keep the if-else logic instead.  Note you should add the initial x to the list before the loop if you also want it included.

Comment: @juharr first advice is working. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string collatz(string input)
{
    int current = 0;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || !int.TryParse(input, out current) || current < 1) {
        return null;
    }
    int max = current;
    while (current > 1) {
        if (current % 2 == 0) {
            current = current / 2;         
            if (current > max)
                max = current;
            if (current != 1)
                input = input + " " + current.ToString();
            if (current == 1) {
                input = input + " " + current.ToString();
                input = input + " largest number was " + max;

            }
        } else {
            if (current == 1) {
                input = input + " " + current.ToString();
                input = input + " largest number was " + max;
            }
            current = (3 * current) + 1;
            if (current > max)
                max = current;
            input = input + " " + current.ToString();
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```